# How to access(or use) database from WebDav Server?

Tags: tomcat, webdav

I want to know how to access (or use) mysql database from WebDav Server. I have setup tomcat WebDav Server. Basically, I want to list the files by querying from database. Any Api is there by using Java. How will be the response? Its an Xml or Json? I have setup the tomcat server by following url. http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-WebDav. Let me know if there are any better documentation.